# Give Manage User Permission to a User without View Setup and Configuration

Tags: administration, permissions, permission-sets, user-management

I have a visualforce page to manage users (deactive, create, edit and reset passwords), but when I add the permissin manage users to the profile, the user with this profile can see the Setup option, there is any way to give the user the permission Manage Users without see Setup option?

Answer (score 0):

No. In order to be able to see a user detail page, you need the View Setup and Configuration permission. This is because the user detail pages are in the Setup menu, so without this permission, you would be unable to see the user detail page in order to perform admin functions.

Answer (score 0):

As you have separate visualforce page for managing users, you should be able to achive this, by moving the logic for manage users (deactive, create, edit and reset passwords) to a separate 'Without Sharing' apex classes .
there is no way to give the user the permission Manage Users without seeing Setup option